# Name of the theorem used for testing the primality of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, primality-test

$n$ is prime $\iff$ $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod n \hspace{10mm} \forall  1 \le a \le n-1$

What is the name of this theorem in literature?

Answer (score 1):

$\Longrightarrow$ is Fermat's little theorem

$\Longleftarrow$ is the definition of prime: any $a<n$ is coprime to $n$, and therefore $n$ must be prime.

Comment: Does the *prime definition* have any other name?

Comment: @hanugm Why would you want another name?

Comment: $\implies$ part is fine but does the other part has any other name other than saying as a prime definition?  Because it is a key property for prime numbers, so I am guessing that some name should be there for that result.

Comment: I want to see for its complete reference, so the name of the theorem would help me a lot.

Comment: @hanugm It's such an immediate consequence of the definition of prime numbers, yet it's relatively specialised. I can't imagine that it has a name. Call the entire thing "Fermat's little theorem", and no one would bat an eye.